# Smileys on php error

Tags: php, replace, error-handling

I'm trying to do

```
<?php
echo str_replace(";)", '<img src=\"path/to/smile_image.gif\" title=\";)\"/>', $message);
?>
```

But when I send a message image does not appear. I viewed it's address and it was
page.url\"path/to/smile_image.gif\

If I remove slashes i receive an error. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Why are you escaping double quotes here ? You are in a simple quoted string, you don't need to.

This is working :

```
<?php
$message = "test ;)";
echo str_replace(";)", '<img src="path/to/smile_image.gif" title=";)"/>', $message);
?>
```

or

```
<?php
$message  = "Test ;)";
echo str_replace(";)", "<img src=\"path/to/smile_image.gif\" title=\";)\"/>", $message);
?>
```